# How to map the "Eject" key on Non-Mac keyboard?

Tags: imac

I've gotten a new USB keyboard for my Mac. It is a Windows keyboard, but after remapping the Alt and Windows keys, it works just like a Mac keyboard. It is missing one particular feature and that is the **"Eject"** key. I'm not sure how to remap that command to another key. Where can I find that command? 
Also if I can assign **volume up** and **volume down** to control the sound from the keyboard.

If anybody knows of a way to resolve this issue, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: In my experience F12 is the eject key on a "Windows Keyboard" plugged into a Mac. you do have to hold it down for a second or two for it to eject an optical disc.

Answer (score 3):

One way you can eject a disk without remapping keys is to use the Eject Menu Extra item.

Just navigate to the `/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/` folder and double-click on the `Eject.menu` file. It will put the 'eject' icon in the menu bar:

[image]

For me, this has worked for both internal and external drives. One click and the drive opens like magic!

**Update**: this Menu item still works in Ventura. It has survived all the updates and upgrades since I first put up this answer in 2017.

Comment: Thanks IconDaemon for your reply, I am looking to "Control + Eject" shortcut to show the shutdown menu to put the iMac in sleep mode quickly.

Comment: How can I map a key on my Microsoft keyboard to the Eject key?
Otherwise, how do I create a new shortcut for locking my screen?

Comment: "I am looking to "Control + Eject" shortcut to show the shutdown menu..." Well then you should edit your question to reflect this!

Comment: any update folks!!!

Answer (score 0):

The shortcut <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> will perform the eject action anytime you have a disk selected in Finder, be it optical, removable, or mounted.